# jquery document click function only working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, webkit, click, drop-down-menu

I'm using dropkick.js to style a select menu. I am trying to make the menu close when you click anywhere outside of the menu. But the removeClass() ( and the document.click() ) are only working on firefox. In webkit, the menu does not close by clicking outside or anywhere else in the document.

Removing the ".dk_open" and ".dk_focus" classes returns the element back to `display:none`, thereby hiding the menu.

Does anyone see anything that might be causing this inconsistency? Thanks!

```
        $('.wpcf7 select').dropkick();

        var $dkopen = $('.dk_open');

        $(document).click(function(){
            $dkopen.removeClass('dk_open dk_focus');
        });

        $dkopen.click(function(){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Comment: Can you set up a demo with http://jsfiddle.net? Where is that code called from? The click handler you setup on `$dkopen` is going to apply to any elements that had the "dk_open" class at the time the code ran - and it will continue to apply to them even once the class is removed, and it will not apply to other elements that have the class added later.

Answer (score 2):

This could use some cleaning up but it worked to solve the issue of drop downs not closing as expected to match native select functionality.

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('.dk_open').removeClass('dk_open');
});

$('.dk_open').live('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.dk_container, .dk_toggle').live('click', function(e){
     $('.dk_open').removeClass('dk_open');
});
```

Added the last event handler to close any open drop downs when selecting another.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but you should try to add a reference to the event in your click function:

```
 $dkopen.click(function(e /*<-- here*/){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue.

Here is a relevant link talking about this: https://github.com/JamieLottering/DropKick/issues/45

Your solution (Corey Aubuchon) does 'work'... in that:

When you click 'Outside' the dropdown, it DOES close...However...

Now, when you click 'Inside' the dropdown (which would be clicking on: "dk_container' or 'dk_toggle') — the dropdown DOES NOT close...

(And, I'm not talking about selecting an 'option' here, what I'm talking about clicking on the same 'down' arrow you click to see the options in the first place)

I'm not a JS developer, I merely combined the solution found here, with the solution from the referenced link, into something that did not give me errors. Somehow it worked though.

Anyway, **Try this instead**...this **works in Chrome, IE, + FF** (you can click inside or outside, in every case it will work :)

```
    $(document).click(function(){$('.dk_open').removeClass('dk_open');});
    $('dk_open').on('click',function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
    $('.dk_container, .dk_toggle').on('click',function(e){var$dk=$(this).parents('.dk_container').first();{$('.dk_open').removeClass('dk_open');$dk.toggleClass('dk_open');}return false;});
```

..or... if you prefer... This is the NOT minified version:

```
    $(document).click(function(){
        $('.dk_open').removeClass('dk_open');
    });
    $('.dk_open').on('click',function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.dk_container, .dk_toggle').on('click',function (e) {

        var $dk  = $(this).parents('.dk_container').first();

        if ( $.browser.webkit ){
            $('.dk_open').removeClass('dk_open');
                $dk.toggleClass('dk_open');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tabindex to each select. After that it will work.
Good luck!